# Authenticate only selected rest end points : spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application exposing few rest endpoints. I wanted to know how we can enable basic authentication only for selected rest endpoints. Let's say I want only `/employee/{id}` request to be authenticated and ignore all the other rest endpoints. I am using the following code. My question is will the `antMatcher` only authenticate the request specified? Currently its enabling authentication for all rest endpoints:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         // How does it work will it only authenticate employee & 
         // ignore any other request?? Its authenticating all the requests currently. 
         http
            .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/employee/*").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();    
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your configuration seems fine to me. Are sure this configuration is getting applied? Are you seeing a random password for the default `user` on the console? Please post your project structure.

Answer (score 13):

By default Spring Boot will secure all endpoints when Spring Security is on the classpath.

You need to explicitly add an exclusion for all other endpoints to be permitted without authentication.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/employee/*").authenticated()
               .anyRequest().permitAll()
             .and()
             .httpBasic()
             .and()
             .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried exact same but not working